# SQL-Server Merge Statement with .NET DataTable

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Background:**
I'm trying to synchronize order information between Oracle and SQL-Server databases and allow users to be able to track any changes between what has been replicated via an ASP.NET web page.  Users will be able to select which line items they want to be able to work on via this page and the remainder will be excluded going forward.  Users will also have the option to change which items have been excluded at any time until the process has been finalized.

The initial load of this order information replicates (from Oracle to SQL-Server) all of the line items and presents them for assignment to the user.  Any subsequent load of the order will compare replicated data to the original data.  I'm using the following statement to handle the replication and reconciliation based on user selections:

```
CREATE TABLE #tempSpecOrderReplication 
( 
    Ord_L_ID INT, 
    Order_Number INT, 
    Ord_ID INT, 
    Item_Number VARCHAR(50), 
    Quantity DECIMAL(18, 2), 
    UOM VARCHAR(50), 
    Price DECIMAL(18, 2), 
    Is_Spec_Order BIT  
); 

INSERT INTO #tempSpecOrderReplication 
([Ord_L_ID], [Ord_ID], [Quantity], [UOM], [Price], 
 [Is_Spec_Order], [Item_Number], [Order_Number]) 
VALUES (...); --These values come from the .NET DataTable

MERGE Spec_Order_Replication WITH (HOLDLOCK) AS target 
USING (SELECT * FROM #tempSpecOrderReplication) AS source 
ON (target.Ord_L_ID = source.Ord_L_ID) 
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    UPDATE SET Is_Spec_Order = source.Is_Spec_Order 
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
    INSERT 
    (Ord_L_ID, Order_Number, Ord_ID, Item_Number, 
     Quantity, UOM, Price, Is_Spec_Order) 
    VALUES 
    (source.Ord_L_ID, source.Order_Number, source.Ord_ID, source.Item_Number, 
     source.Quantity, source.UOM, source.Price, source.Is_Spec_Order); 

DROP TABLE #tempSpecOrderReplication
```

**Questions:**

1. Is there any way I can improve the existing SQL statement?
2. Is there a better way that I can go about this?

I'm using SQL-Server version 2008 R2.

Please ask if you need any further information.

Comment: Are there any specific areas in which you would want it to be better?  For example, are you concerned about performance, fault-tolerance, something else, or all of the above?  Also, is this a one-way replication and how frequently is this query run?

Comment: @xDaevax I've read a couple articles about the `MERGE` statement not necessarily being an atomic statement causing some issues with race conditions.  This is a one-way replication, only going from my Oracle instance to my SQL-Server instance.  The order values are compared each time the user saves their work and this statement will be ran each time the user is forced to update the current replicated data.  Hard to say exactly, but basically only when the original order data is changed.

Comment: So, your ASP.NET code is bound to Oracle, then replicated to SQL Server, correct?

Comment: @xDaevax Correct, the ASP.NET DataTable referenced is bound to Oracle and being replicated to SQL-Server.

Comment: sounds like you could use a Gridview to do this, like you could have the load be from one database and the insert and update be on the other database, and could have an insert button that inserts all records, etc.

Comment: @Malachi that's basically what I'm doing.  I'm loading a Telerik RadGrid with the data from Oracle, the user is selecting which line items need to be worked on (via CheckBoxes) and then that data is replicated via an ASP Button click.

Comment: so you are sending the information to both Databases on the button click?

Comment: @Malachi no information is being sent/updated to the Oracle database during this step.  It is only being pulled from Oracle and replicated to the SQL-Server instance, tagged based on the user's selections via the RadGrid.

Comment: are you putting a check mark next to the ones that should be sent to the new Database (relative to the record) and then sending them in bulk at the click of a button?

Comment: @Malachi I'm not tracking and filtering for individual changes.  I am sending them in bulk so that I can process the whole batch as a set operation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Well done.

I honestly cannot find anything bad to say about your SQL code. Your capitalization of keywords and indentation are consistent. Your query is properly explicit, there is no guessing work that the SQL engine would have to make. You clean up after your operation by dropping your `#tempSpecOrderReplication`.

The only thing that looked unusual, though not bad, is that you used square brackets in this clause but nowhere else. I would personally prefer if it were consistent thoughout, if I had to maintain it. But it's just a nitpick.

```
INSERT INTO #tempSpecOrderReplication 
([Ord_L_ID], [Ord_ID], [Quantity], [UOM], [Price], 
 [Is_Spec_Order], [Item_Number], [Order_Number]) 
VALUES (...); --These values come from the .NET DataTable
```

Comment: Good spot on the `[]`'s, I forget to use those consistently.

Comment: @MichaelMcGriff, you only need the brackets when you are using a keyword as a column, or your table name has spaces or the column name has spaces, etc. if your names are weird and the SQL Engine doesn't like them put them in Square Brackets. otherwise it's a waste of characters, and personally it makes the code clunky

Comment: @Malachi you're right of course.  I got into the habit of using them as SSMS provides them for you on all of their auto-generated queries and it makes it easier for me to tell exactly what RBDMS I'm querying against by a simple glance.

Comment: square brackets help to search for fields in text searches, since the field names are often part of other variable names

Answer (score 3):

I don't know that I would create a Temporary table to do this.

You have two things that you are doing here

1. Inserting if the record doesn't exist
2. updating the record if a record with the same ID already exists

I think that instead of a MERGE I would just use an If Then Statement.  I always think about keeping it simple, and I think that using an If Statement would be much simpler than trying to Merge a Temp Table into an Existing table.

It would look something like this

```
DECLARE @Ord_L_ID INT --a very important input variable
DECLARE @Is_Spec_Order BIT
DECLARE @Order_Number INT
DECLARE @Ord_ID INT
DECLARE @Item_Number INT
DECLARE @Quantity INT
DECLARE @UOM INT -- Wasn't sure what this was Guessed it was another INT
DECLARE @Price Decimal -- There is also Money and SmallMoney DataTypes

-- ETC.

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Spec_Order_Replication AS SOR WHERE SOR.Ord_L_ID = @Ord_L_ID)
    UPDATE Spec_Order_Replication
    SET 
        Is_Spec_Order = @Is_Spec_Order
    WHERE 
        Ord_L_ID = @Ord_L_ID
ELSE
    INSERT INTO Spec_Order_Replication
    (
        @Ord_L_ID
        , @Order_Number
        , @Ord_ID
        , @Item_Number
        , @Quantity
        , @UOM
        , @Price
        , @Is_Spec_Order
    )
```

This should be housed in a stored procedure so that you can call it from your Application using whatever data is sent to it.

Forcing the assignment of the table's Primary Key is a little weird but makes sense in this circumstance, but be careful because it could cause issues.

---

Your code does this

- takes a comma delimited list
- creates a temporary table
- inserts records into the Temporary Table
- Merges a permanent table to a Temporary Table on an ID

  - ID may or may not exist
- finds the matches

  - updates table
- finds where there are no matches

  - inserts into permanent table

my code does this

- takes in data for a row
- determines if data exists in permanent table

  - if it exists the permanent table is updated
  - if it doesn't exist new data is inserted into the permanent table

My code does far less than your code, and as such will be much more efficient and take up less processing on the server, regardless of the fact that the procedure will be called once for every row of data.

Comment: Won't I have to do this row-by-row then?  I'm specifically trying to avoid doing that.

Comment: you were inserting into the Temporary table `row by row` as well.

Comment: I'm not actually, I truncated that part of it for brevity.  I build the entire values list via a LINQ query out of the DataTable so that it's one large INSERT statement.

Comment: so you send the DataTable to your SPROC. it should function the same way.  they are both stored procedures, I don't have enough of the code to explain how to do it with your code or to be able to tell if I am wrong.  what does the code look like inside of `Values(...);`?

Comment: It's just a comma delimited listing of groups of values.  For example: `VALUES (1,2,3,4,5), (2,3,4,5,6)` with each grouping containing applicable values selected from each DataRow.

Comment: you should be able to connect the DataGrid to this SPROC on the UPDATE Field. and then have a button at the end to update all rows.  whether you go "row by row" or send the values in a Comma Delimited List you are still inserting Row by Row, that is how an SQL Engine works. process it one record at a time, it should be more efficient than sending a large Comma Delimited List and waiting for it to Create the temp table then insert all the info into the table then  call the merge function and figure out if where the temp matches the permanent.

Comment: My (possibly incorrect) impression was that the `IF...EXISTS` approach was slightly less efficient and more prone to race conditions than the `MERGE` approach, which is why I was doing it this way at all.  I'll test your approach to see for sure one way or the other.  Thank you for your review.

Comment: I'm doubtful about this answer. As @MichaelMcGriff pointed out, it is typically better to use a set based approach.